# How to set permissions for each user in symfony2

Tags: symfony, security, permissions

A blog contains some posts, this site enables user to show,edit,delete,rating posts. my problem is some users only list the post and rate it, some users have permission to edit and delete post. admin have a permission to change the user permissions. How to implement in Symfony 2

Answer (score 0):

[Symfony Voters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html) are what you are looking for.

Comment: Code please???? I can't guess what how you decided to implement your Voter... You probably messed up in your Voter implementation.

Comment: Please give me an example of voter like my situation

Comment: I don't have time for that, and Stack Overflow is not a place where people code for you. The Symfony documentation is clear enough to help you build this. If you're still lost, check [this section](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html#creating-the-custom-voter) of the doc, it's the example you need.